# "Operation in progress..." Never Ends When Previewing Rows in Kettle Spoon via Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, pentaho, kettle, spoon

I am trying to pull data from a Salesforce API account using Pentaho/Kettle Spoon. I am able to establish a connection on Pentaho with this account. I am also able to get fields from specific modules. However, when I try and "Preview rows" (even with a small number of rows), the "Operation in Progress" window comes up and never completes the task. When I try and cancel the job, Pentaho hangs and I have to force quit it.

I am running Fedora 21. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you see anything in the log file?

Comment: what is the volume of data u r previewing. i assume the data volume is large which might be consuming a lot of memory!!

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

Since upgrading to Fedora 22 Spoon (the client tool of PDI) was not working properly anymore. Although I could start Spoon properly and create transformations etc, once I wanted to execute a transformation or sometimes even when trying to open settings, nothing was working and the terminal window showed several (SWT:20352): GLib-CRITICAL error messages. In a nutshell, Spoon was rendered useless.

Here is how to solve this:

1. Go to the Eclipse Download Page and download the latest 64bit verion of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. Note: There is a separate download area for SWT; however, for Linux there is no 64 bit version available. The only way to get one is to build it yourself. So I just went the easier way and downloaded Eclipse instead.
2. Unzip the file and search for swt. A search result will show a few files, but the ones interesting for us are (your version number might be different): `org.eclipse.swt_3.103.2.v20150203-1313.jar` and `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar`.
3. Copy the first one of these files into `<PDI_HOME>/libswt/linux/x86` and the second into `<PDI_HOME>/libswt/linux/x86_64`.
4. oth folders still have the original jar files in them. Rename them to `swt-jar-old` (Note: no extension, so that they are not picked up).
5. Start Spoon. There will be a few error messages shown, but so far Spoon is working way better for me than before.

FONT: http://diethardsteiner.github.io/pdi/2015/06/07/Fixing-PDI-GLib-CRITICAL.html

Comment: 2018. Still helps

Answer (score 0):

i'm running Ubuntu 14.04, i5,6gb RAM, got same trouble..

when i check, the load in proccessor is 100%, evertime i try showing the content or other thing in pentaho, the Operation in progress is show up, and never end..

How to solve, check your access to file/connection in your database,unrecognize file,field,etc. after this resolve, my proccessor run normal, and i could run / execute the transformation.